# how do you handle a variable in a deleted namespace?

Tags: tcl

Doing some exploration involving creating and deleting namespaces, I ran into this curiosity:

```
% namespace eval foo {variable x 1}
% namespace upvar foo x x
% set x
1
% namespace delete foo
% set x
can't read "x": no such variable
% set x 2
can't set "x": upvar refers to variable in deleted namespace
%
```

After this, `x` seems to be untouchable.  It can't be read or unset because it doesn't exist, but it can't be set because it's in another namespace.  How can `x` be recovered from this state?

What I'm trying to accomplish is importing a set of commands and variables from another namespace, and being able to remove that namespace and have the imported commands and variables go away.  `namespace delete` seems to do the right thing with regards to imported commands, but there is no equivalent for imported variables, and as far as I can tell there isn't even any way to tell if a particular variable is imported (via `namespace upvar`) from somewhere else - `namespace which` tells you the current namespace, and `namespace origin` doesn't exist for variables.

Comment: Stopping variables from being links (the internal mechanism used for `upvar`, `global`, etc.) is... tricky. Very tricky. The problem is that virtually all operations are passed through to the underlying variable that is the target of the link.

Answer (score 1):

(not an answer)

Looks like a bug to me => https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcl/tktnew

You can't unset the variable either. It seems like the only thing you can do is `upvar` it to a different variable.

```
% namespace eval foo {variable x 1}
% namespace upvar foo x x
% namespace delete foo
% set x
can't read "x": no such variable
% set x 1
can't set "x": upvar refers to variable in deleted namespace
% unset x
can't unset "x": no such variable
% set tmp ""
% upvar 0 tmp x
% unset x
```

Answer (score 0):

> What I'm trying to accomplish is importing a set of commands and
>   variables from another namespace, and being able to remove that
>   namespace and have the imported commands and variables go away.

As your posting is more about this buggy behaviour of the `upvar` mechanism (and the lacking of Tcl's introspection), your overall motivation comes only as a sidenote. Maybe you can realize sth. along the lines of the following, as an alternative (to avoid `upvar`)?

```
% namespace eval foo {variable x 1; proc bar {} {;}}
% apply {{} {variable x; puts $x; bar; namespace delete [namespace current]; set x "a"; puts $x} ::foo}
1
a
% apply {{} {variable x; puts $x; bar; namespace delete [namespace current]; set x "a"; puts $x} ::foo}
namespace "::foo" not found
% namespace eval foo {variable x 2; proc bar {} { puts BAR}}
% apply {{} {variable x; puts $x; bar; namespace delete [namespace current]; set x "a"; puts $x} ::foo}
2
BAR
a
```

- You trade a namespace environment for a proc environment as an "import" target, and `variable` is not affected by the zombie links of `upvar`.
- You can swap the context namespace, or re-create a deleted one as you wish.
- You don't need two mechanisms (`namespace import` and `namespace upvar`), just one.
- Flipping the context namespace will incur the loss of the lambdaExpr's intrep (incl. bytecode), so maybe better keep recreating the namespace `::foo`.